# Adding sortInfo and/or filterValue to DataGrid breaks sorting/filtering functionality

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-data-grid

I am trying to add some 'save preferences' functionality to a DataGrid using https://reactdatagrid.io/docs/miscellaneous but when I add sortInfo makes columns unsortable, the same happens for filterValue (trying to save filtering strings/data). Code here:

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import DataGrid from '@inovua/reactdatagrid-enterprise';
import { columnFilters, eeOverviewColumns, filterTypes } from "./overview-columns";
import '@inovua/reactdatagrid-enterprise/index.css';
import { TypeRowProps, TypeRowSelection } from '@inovua/reactdatagrid-community/types';
import { TypeOnSelectionChangeArg } from "@inovua/reactdatagrid-community/types/TypeDataGridProps"
import { Button, FormControl, MenuItem, Select, SelectChangeEvent, TextField } from '@mui/material';
import { TypeColumn, TypeFilterValue, TypeSortInfo } from '@inovua/reactdatagrid-enterprise/types';
 
interface StoreLayout {
    columns: TypeColumn[];
    sortInfo: TypeSortInfo;
    columnOrder : string[];
    filterValue: TypeFilterValue;
}
 
let STORE: StoreLayout = {
    columns: eeOverviewColumns,
    sortInfo: [],
    columnOrder: eeOverviewColumns.map(ee => ee.name) as string[],
    filterValue: columnFilters,
}
 
let VIEWS= [
    {
        id: 0,
        name: "Default view",
        state: STORE
    }
]
 
const EEOverview = (props: any) => {
    const dataSource = props.eeData
 
    // Checkbox selection
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState<TypeRowSelection>();
 
    const onSelectionChange = useCallback(
        (config: TypeOnSelectionChangeArg) => {
            setSelected(config.selected)
        },
        [],
    );
 
 
    const goToEe = useCallback((rowProps: TypeRowProps) => {
        window.location.href = `${window.location.href}/${rowProps.data.key}`;
    }, [])
 
 
 
    const initialState = Object.assign({}, STORE, {});
    const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
 
    const [viewName, setViewName] = useState('')
    const sendViewName = (viewName: string) => { setViewName(viewName) }
    const saveState = () => {
        if (!viewName || viewName.length === 0 ) {
            alert("View name not provided")
            return
        }
        STORE = {
            columnOrder: state.columnOrder,
            columns: state.columns,
            sortInfo: state.sortInfo,
            filterValue: state.filterValue
        }
        setState(Object.assign({}, state, {}))
 
        if(VIEWS.map(view => view.name).some(name => name === viewName)) {
            const view = VIEWS.find(view => view.name === viewName)!
            view.state = state
        } else {
            VIEWS.push({
                id: VIEWS.length,
                name: viewName,
                state: state
            })
        }
    }
    const onSortInfoChange = (sortInfo: TypeSortInfo) => {
        setState(Object.assign({}, state, { sortInfo }));
    }
 
    const onColumnOrderChange = (columnOrder: string[]) => {
        setState(Object.assign({}, state, { columnOrder }));
    }
 
    const onFilterValueChange = (filterValue: TypeFilterValue) => {
        setState(Object.assign({}, state, { filterValue }));
    }
 
    const onBatchColumnResize = (batchColumnInfo: any, { reservedViewportWidth }: any) => {
        const colsMap = batchColumnInfo.reduce((acc: any, colInfo: any) => {
            const { column, width, flex } = colInfo
            acc[column.name] = { width, flex }
            return acc
        }, {})
 
        const columns = state.columns.map((c: any) => {
            return Object.assign({}, c, colsMap[c.name])
        })
 
        setState(Object.assign({}, state, {
            columns,
            reservedViewportWidth
        }))
    }
 
    return (
        <div>
            <ViewSelector state = {state} onChange = {setState} ></ViewSelector>
            <ViewText onChange = {sendViewName} ></ViewText>
            <Button sx={{ mx: 2, my: 2, minWidth: 80 }} variant="contained"
                onClick = {saveState}
                >
                Save view
            </Button>
            <DataGrid
                idProperty="key"
                theme="default-light"
                className="data-grid"
                defaultFilterValue={columnFilters}
                filterTypes={filterTypes}
                filterValue={state.filterValue} //<- here
                onRowClick={goToEe}
                columns={state.columns}
                sortInfo={state.sortInfo}       //<- and here
                columnOrder={state.columnOrder}
                pagination="local"
                dataSource={dataSource}
                onSelectionChange={onSelectionChange}
                sortable={true}
                checkboxColumn
                selected={selected}
                enableSelection={true}
                onSortInfoChange={onSortInfoChange}
                onBatchColumnResize={onBatchColumnResize}
                onColumnOrderChange={onColumnOrderChange}
                onFilterValueChange={onFilterValueChange}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
export default EEOverview;
 
const ViewText = ({onChange}: {onChange: any}) => {
    const onViewNameChange = (viewName: string) => {
        onChange(viewName)
    }
    return (
        <TextField sx={{ mx: 2, my: 2 }}
            id="search"
            variant="outlined"
            size="small"
            label="Name current view"
            onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => { onViewNameChange(e.target.value) }}
        />
    )
}
 
const ViewSelector = ({state, onChange}: {state:any, onChange: any}) => {
 
    const [selectedView, setSelectedView] = useState(0)
 
    const handleViewChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent<number>) => {
        const selectedView = VIEWS.find(view => view.id===event.target.value)!
        setSelectedView(selectedView.id)
        const selectedState = selectedView.state
        onChange(Object.assign({},selectedState, {}))
    }
 
    return (
        <FormControl sx={{ m: 2, minWidth: 140 }} >
            <Select labelId="view" variant="standard" size="medium" value={selectedView}
                renderValue={(selected: any) => { return <div>{VIEWS[selected].name}</div>; }}
                onChange={handleViewChange}>
                {VIEWS.map((val, key) => (
                    <MenuItem value={key}>{val.name}</MenuItem>
                ))}
            </Select>
        </FormControl>
    )
}
```

If I remove sortInfo/filterValue from passing to DataGrid, it behaves correctly, but it won't be saved to preferences.

Tried to move dataSource from props to state but it has the same behaviour

Comment: For whom it may concern, the problem was that change handler listeners didn't manipulate dataSource so it remained the same. Thus onSortInfoChange, onFilterValueChange should sort/filter data as seen here https://reactdatagrid.io/docs/sorting#controlled-and-uncontrolled-sorting